# R - Unknown issue with class of data variables

Tags: r

When I use this function:

```
sapply(data, class)
```

To get the class of each of the variable in given data I get `logical` as the class for every variable, although data variables are a mix of percentages, numbers, dates and years.

Comment: And noone else will either because we have no idea what your data looks like. Can you `dput(head(data))` so we have something to go on?

Comment: @Vsg Please `dput` your data within the question

Comment: @Vsg - look at your data - every value is `logical(0)` All of your data are actually just names of columns in a `data.frame` - see `colnames(data)`

Comment: @thelatemail That's my question why is it coming like that although I have integers in my data? Sorry I am new to R so don't know much

Comment: @Vsg You don't have any integers in the data you added to the question. They are all logical.

Comment: @Vsg - how did you get this `data` into R? I suspect something is wrong with an importing procedure.

Comment: There are also 0 rows of data. Is it possible that all of your data have been stored as column names? How many rows were there supposed to be?

Comment: @thelatemail I just imported the data using read.csv like how we normally do....thanks I will look into the data once.

Comment: @Vsg if you attach a link to the .csv in the question then we can help you further

Comment: @Hack-R There is only one row of data without any headers for 62 columns

Comment: @Vsg Ah, then that's the problem. You read in (or later converted) all of the data as headers.

Comment: Try `read.csv("textfile.csv", header=FALSE)` - you need to force R to not read the first line into a header.

Comment: @thelatemail Thanks. It now shows classes to be factors,integers and numeric!